# Android: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String) command is too slow? or I am doing something wrong?

Tags: java, android, runtime

I am trying to create an app which I use it for remote control an android device(TV). Actually I did it however when I click a button on the controller device(mobile), it takes apprx. 1 sec to do the work in the device(TV) that I want to control.

When I checked all logs in the code and I see that method spends that much time...

```
    String commandStr;
    commandStr = String.format("%s"," input keyevent "+keyCode);

    try {
        process = runTimeExec(commandStr);
        runTimeExec(commandStr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

And the runTimeExec defined as;

```
    public static Process runTimeExec(String commandStr) throws IOException {  
           Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandString);

    }
```

I just wanna learn if there is any other solution to run command immediately on the TV device itself? Or how can I make faster this code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the getevent/sendevent code for this purpose. Its very fast and works immediately on the TV device. Just try it. You can find detailed documentations in https://source.android.com

Answer (score 0):

Oğuz Gençer mean this :

```
Instrumentation backExecutor = new Instrumentation();
backExecutor.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```